# Android - How to perform an action until a Handler doesn't complete the delay

Tags: android, handler

I have an app where the user can rate a post with a like/dislike.
After that I show a view with the autor of the post for a second and update the content with another article.

The code that I am using right now for this delay is:

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
                            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    nextFragment();
                                }
                            }, 1000);
```

I would like to provide a share functionality after the user rate the article, that will appear just for this second.
But I don't have any ideas of how to do it. 
How can I show this view with the author for a second, and in case of the user click the share button, I perform the share action and comeback to the next article after that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Well why don't you just do your *action* before starting the handler, and cancel that action when the handler completes? Example:

```
final ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
dialog.setTitle("Something something");
dialog.show();
Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        dialog.dismiss();
        nextFragment();
    }
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Is it is not a ProgressDialog, but instead a button that I turn the visible on and after the delay I turn off. What happens if the action of the user when he clicks the button take more than one second?

Comment: @user3249186 it's unclear what do you mean by **action**. Do you mean when the user clicks a button the timer should stop/reset?